# How do we define the number of row per page?

Tags: antd

How do we define the number of rows per page on the table? like 10, 25, 50 etc, So we can set a number of rows on the same page according to user wish. looking like same like columns we can add pageRowCount={25 or 50 or all }

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it's in the [pagination component documentation](https://ant.design/components/pagination/)
You can pass it to table Component as a prop  `pagination={{ pageSize: 50 }}`